# Why would an STM32 flight controller need programming interfaces other than USB?

Tags: pcb, usb, stm32, swd

I am new to STM32 chips. I am currently working on a self driving airplane and I have realized that the processing power of an Arduino is not enough so I decided to try to create a custom PCB as a flight controller that will have a STM32F756NGH6 as the main processor. While designing the PCB I read that I should not use USB for programming but SWD interface. After googling I could not find anything that could explain why I should not use USB. USB would be a much simpler and cheaper solution. The datasheet also says the this chip is capable of USB communication so I really do not see any reason not to use it.

Comment: Use a USB ST-LINK programmer. so convenient.

Comment: Making a custom board is commendable in the sense that evaluation boards aren't fit to fly.  However, generally you should have a lot more practical experience with a chip before you set off to specify or design a board based around it.  At this point you should seriously consider getting an eval board for your target chip or one of its close relatives, getting eval/breakout boards for your sensors, etc and wiring them all up on a bench or stuck to a piece of wood you can tilt and bank.

Comment: Don't be like the people who try to *fly* such lashups - making a small unitary board you can put in a tiny, less hazardous aircraft is indeed the right path.  But don't make your board too soon, either - use the time with the eval board setup to get a better sense of what you really need on your custom board, including things like understanding the distinct roles of SWD, UARTs, and USB - something which will lead you to realize as others who have gone before, that USB is something to maybe use late in the design cycle when you are refining details of high-level behavior, not when starting up.

Comment: The newer stm32 parts (STM32G) are moving away from the bootloader.  No matter what part/vendor/family read the datasheet understand your options, if for example swd is available, put a couple of pads down if possible as a back door, debug, etc.  Also need to think about what if I brick it, you will want to have a boot0 path so you can program it in curcuit...Not all stm32 parts with usb support the dfu-util bootloader, if this is a flight controller adding the connector and voltage regulator is a bit of a waste, where uart or swd is just some copper.

Comment: with the uart path you can both program (currently most stm32s) and debug via uart output.  with the swd path you can both program and debug by periodically stopping and starting the core.   usb is just program, reset, hope it works, program, reset, hope it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can program firmware via USB just fine, that is not a problem. It is perfectly good for firmware updates.

Why you should have SWD interface is not because of programming the MCU, but debugging the firmware.

It would be pretty anemic to have high performance MCU there, and you are limited to debugging code problems over serial console, LEDs, pushbuttons etc, instead of using a proper tool for that.

Comment: Even if you don't use breakpoint debugging, there remains the issue that USB is pretty much all-or-nothing.  Either your code is mostly operational and you can communicate with it via USB, or it is failing and you can do absolutely nothing with the USB but invoke (by some other means) the factory USB bootloader and try again.  And USB breaks when you hit a breakpoint or simply stop servicing it.  Realistically any STM32 board should include not just SWD, but also a UART which can be used to send debug messages without needing everything to work perfectly.

Comment: On many STM32's the pins used for USB also have a UART option, but if you do that, then you can't have UART messages *while* trying to figure out what is wrong with the USB...

Answer (score -1):

You will need to program the STM32 with a boot loader to be able to talk to it via USB. I will suggest that you add the SWD interface to your PCB for programming and debugging.

Comment: So its better because I do not need to load a boot loader to the chip and I can save space in the flash memory for the code that I upload?

Comment: The answer is wrong. F756 contains a bootloader that supports USB DFU.

Comment: That menas that I do not have to add the SWD interface and I can get the exact same result that I would get if I added it?

Comment: No, it does not mean that. See my answer.

Comment: Sorry, at first i didn't see that

Comment: In some of ST's early USB-capable MCU's (like the STM32F103 people play with on the "bluepill" boards) the factory ROM bootloader cannot speak USB.  But in pretty much all of the later ones, it can.